# how to sort array of objects in descending order in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
  public addition :any = [];
  public display : any = [];
  public object1 =['3','2','1'];
  public value2 =['5','7','9','8'];
  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit(){
     this.addition=this.object1.concat(this.value2);
     this.display=this.addition.sort();
  }
```

how to sort the array in descending order using typescript in angular 2 or above versions
[Complete code Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9azhea?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just pass a function to the sort, based on which you want to sort the array

```
.sort((a,b) => b - a)
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfu77q)

Answer (score 5):

Your code

```
this.display=this.addition.sort();
```

will sort the array in ascending order, to sort in descending order you need to pass a comparator function.

```
this.display=this.addition.sort((a,b) => b - a);
```